# What does power mean at linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

What does power at operator mean ? does it mean it have a composition of 2 identical operator or just simply multiplicating 2 operator ? im new to algebra linear and have a problem to prove an operator is projection. Can you guys give me an example of power operator ?
What does $T^{2}$ mean at this operator ?

$A\in M_{n\times n}$

$T : A \to (A+A^{t})/2$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $T^k$ means the $k$-fold composition $\underbrace{T\circ T\circ\cdots\circ T}_{k \text{ times}}$ of $T$ with itself, so that $T^2x=T(Tx),\,T^3x=T(T(Tx)),\ldots$, etc. for every vector $x$. The specific $T$ in your question is idempotent, so that $T=T^2=T^3=\cdots$. Note that the ‘vectors’ in your question are matrices from the vector space $M_{n\times n}$.

Comment: If you can imagine a projection *geometrically*, you will realise that, once you've projected a vector onto something, if you try to project it *again* it just maps into itself. This justifies the definition of projection: operator $T$ is a *projection* if, once applied once, it acts on the image as identity. In other words, $T(T(x))=T(x)$ for all vectors $x$. Now, this means that the operator. $T^2=T\circ T$ is the same operator as $T$, so we can define a *projection* to be any linear operator  $T$ such that $T^2=T$.

Answer (score 2):

It just means applying the linear operator twice: $T^2(A)=T(T(A))=T\left(\frac{A+A^t}{2}\right)=\frac{\left(\frac{A+A^t}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{A+A^t}{2}\right)^t}{2}=\frac{2\left(\frac{A+A^t}{2}\right)}{2}=\frac{A+A^t}{2}=T(A)$
where $A\in M^{n\times n}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Therefore, $T(A)=T^k(A)$ ($k\in\mathbb{N}$) and your linear operator is indempotent and is called a projection.

Comment: yes I edited it, I missed a $+$

Comment: ahh i see, thank youuu ! :D